Does Ubuntu server have trash and what happens when I delete files?
I made myself a home media server using HP mini PC, Ubuntu server and Plex. I use WinSCP for transferring and deleting files.
My question is, does Ubuntu server have some sort of trash/recycle bin? I deleted a few movies I don't need anymore and it seems to me my disk space still stays the same (I also checked disk space using WinSCP).
Do I need to do anything else besides just deleting the files through WinSCP?
Is there any way to check if the files are truly deleted?
Thanks!

Please [edit] your question and clarify how you deleted the files. Do you use some sort of graphical tool? And how are you then checking the disk space?

WinSCP is a file transfer application. As it is not an Ubuntu application, we don't know how its "delete" feature works nor how it updates you about disk space. Those seem like good questions to ask WinSCP support. If you were you logging into your Ubuntu server using SSH, we would recommend using ls -l before and after a delete to confirm the storage size change. And, if you are using stock Ubuntu Server without any add-ons, there would be no Trash. No undo.

@graham in this case, the OP has specifically stated that disk space remains the same after deleting, so I don't think this is a dupe. The dupe target just asks if a default Server installation has some sort of "recycling bin" and the answer of course is no, but that doesn't explain what the OP has seen here.

Since the server having trash question is answered well elsewhere, this question should be edited to focus on the disk space issue
